# Is there a "clean" way to get POSTs in object oriented PHP?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

Let's say we have a simple HTML form like the one below:

```
 <form action="Controller.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="product">
    <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="price">

    <button type="submit">send</button>
 </form>
```

The question is, is there a clean way to get POSTs in a class? Here on Stack I've seen many questions whose answers say to get the requests as below, using the requests in the constructor to initialize the attributes:

```
<?php
    class ControllerProduct
    {
        private $product;
        private $price;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->product = $_POST['product'];
            $this->price   = $_POST['price'];
        }
    }
?>
```

But this way wouldn't violate the concept of SOLID since here the class is knowing where the data comes from? Is there a way to make the code cleaner following clean development standards or is there not much to do in this case?

Comment: So *just* make it public function __construct($product, $price)?

Comment: This code is not a controller though and the entire mess is not MVC. To become a controller, it will have to be created with a Request class dependency, so inside of this Controller you can work with $this->request in order to access POST variables. You desperately need to work with some PHP framework like Symfony to get the idea

Comment: A very clean way is to use an implementation of [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/) and [PSR-17](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-17/). Like the library [laminas-diactoros](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-diactoros/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

(object)$_POST to convert array to object

```js
<?php
    class ControllerProduct
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            return (object)$_POST;
        }
    }
?>
```